Best stotra or mantra to increase will power?
I want to know stptras which can give unshakable will power like person can withstand anything

Pick any name of lord and keep chanting it you will get immense will power and do satsanga with it

Mantras require will-power inherently in the chanter for them to give results. Otherwise one would chant them for a few days and then give up. Suggest listening to Satsangs of self-realized saints, following their teachings, and then chanting the Mantra taught by them for a period of time. One will notice that their will-power has naturally improved.

Gayatri Mantra will do it.

ॐ भूर्भुवः स्वः  तत्स॑वि॒तुर्वरे॑ण्यं॒  भर्गो॑ दे॒वस्य॑ धीमहि।  धियो॒
योनः॑ प्रचो॒दया॑त्॥
oṃ bhūr bhuvaḥ svaḥ tat savitur vareṇyaṃ bhargo devasya dhīmahi dhiyo
yo naḥ pracodayāt


Gayatri mantra is to increase intelligence

But one should get it from guru only not from any online texts
